# A tool like force.com logins but open on multiple sessions?

Tags: tools

As a Salesforce developer, I always work on multiple SFDC sessions. Remembering all the login credentials is a big convenience. Force.com logins for Chrome is good. But it still opens tabs/windows in the same session. The only way to start a new session is via incognito mode which will still have only two active sessions.

Some multiple session tools like multilogin for Chrome and multifox for Firefox might help in this way. But it seems to me that multilogin is not collaborating well with multilogin. Any tools that might help achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are now using multi-login plugin for Chrome and Keepass to keep the credentials which synergize pretty well.